# Gsettigs and dconf to set hotkey

Tags: ubuntu, global-hotkey

Hello 
 I need to set a hotkey in ubuntu 12.10, i use

gsettings(dconf)

```
~$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding '<Primary><Alt>s'
~$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding '<Primary><Alt>s'
~$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ command 'gnome-terminal'
```

but when i watch this schema i just see

```
~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
~$ @as []
```

but when i use dconf  to see this schema

```
~$ dconf list /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/
binding
command
```

what i am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the value for the parent key: `custom-keybindings` which is of type `@as[]`. First check if it's empty with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
```

If it's empty: `[]` , run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/']"
```

If it's not empty you will have to add the existing values to the above command (values must be surrounded by single quotes and separated by comma + space, like `['val1', 'val2', 'val3']`). And then run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/custom2/ binding '<Primary><Alt>s'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/custom2/ command 'gnome-terminal'
```