# Registering global hotkeys with only commandline

Tags: java, global-hotkey

Is it possible to bind a hotkey and wait for a certain key combination but globally so that I can be in other applications and still use the hotkey.

The project is specifically for windows OS so a OS dependant solution is fine.

This is a really small question but I couldn't find any solution except for Linux.

Comment: the application isn't using a GUI its just using the commandline

Comment: they are hard coded for now

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379164/gsettigs-and-dconf-to-set-hotkey